# Mail() Function unexpectantly sending to unspecified/called/passed emails

Tags: php, email

It's very strange and I don't know why, but when I pass my '$to' string to the mail() function, for some unknown reason, It sends to all users in the database, instead of just those being passed into the $to string.

EXAMPLE: I pass the following it.
        'User1 , Mod1 '

Result: On the positive side, all those listed receive emails as intended. But so does everyone else which makes me feel like i'm spamming some folks unintentionally with notices they don't want/didn't ask for/have nothing to do with them.

```
'User1 <user1@example.com>, User2 <user2@example.com>, User3 <user3@example.com>, User4 <user4@example.com>, User5 <user5@example.com>, Mod5 <mod5@example.com>'
```

I have been through my script several times, and I have var_dump() and xDebugged the $to variable just before and after 'Mail()' is called, and the string shows only the people I expect for the mail function to send to, yet it still sends too all users. I am using php 5.6 currently on DreamHost. It works in my local host (Ampps), but when i go live, its very unexpected results in which everyone is, as previously mentioned, received the email notifications.

This is how I set up the variables to send via mail()

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: ' . $to;
$headers[] = 'From: myDomain - ' . $ttl . ' <noreply@myDomain.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: ' . MOD_EMAILS;
$headers[] = 'Bcc: xxxxxxx@gmail.com';

//var_dumped() //i var_dump here, string was as expected

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

//var_dumped() //var_dump here, string was as expected
```

Does anyone have/have had an experience like this? Or an idea of how to resolve it? I'm a newbie and trying to build my own CMS as a means of teaching myself to write PHP and stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to post the db code

Comment: Do you mean the code which i built the db from or the sql calls to the db? Sorry, but i'm not very advanced and I'm trying new stuff like working with SQL.

Comment: I solved the issue, which had as I thought nothing to do with he database or any of the sql calls. Rather, it had to do with the fact that I had the $to variable both in the $headers and then also in the actual mail() function call, along with the $variable. By commenting out the $headers[] = $to, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, which had as I thought nothing to do with he database or any of the sql calls. Rather, it had to do with the fact that I had the $to variable both in the $headers and then also in the actual mail() function call, along with the $variable. By commenting out the $headers[] = $to, the issue was solved.